# Implementing Kalman filter in R

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter

I am attempting to implement a Kalman filter in R.  Working from "Time Series Analysis" by Hamilton the state space equations are defined as:

State: $z(t) = F_z(t-1) + v(t)$

Observation: $y(t) = A'x(t) + H'z(t-1) + w(t)$

Where $x(t)$ are exogenous variables.  The model I am attempting to implement is defined this way.  There are multiple packages that implement state space models in R, but through reading the documentation it appears that the equations are defined differently, with $A'x(t)$ including in the state equation.  Short of writing the maximum likelihood estimation code myself, does anyone know a way to fit this model in R?

Update:

Deleted my past update.  I found another paper that implements this in a way that is much more clear, will update after I have digested it.

Update 2:
So I found another paper that does something similar to what I am attempting, but it is much more clear to me how to set up the state space equations.  The problem I am running into now is running the filter using package dlm.  If anyone has any experience that would help I would be greatful.  I am able to set up the model, and then run the filter, but only 2 filtered values are returned (initial state and t=1) as opposed to t-values.  I am not really clear why that is.

From the dlm documentation:

Observation: $y= \mathbf{F}\theta + v_t$

State: $\theta = \mathbf{G}\theta_{t-1} +w_t$

Where m is the number of observations and p is the number of parameters in $\mathbf{F}$

- $\mathbf{V}$ is m x m
- $\mathbf{G}$ is p x p
- $\mathbf{W}$ is p x p
- $c_0$ is p x p

Sample code:

```
require(dlm)

FMat<-cbind(rnorm(123),rnorm(123))  
GMat<-diag(1,2)
WMat<-diag(0.02,2)
Vmat<-diag(0.02,123)

m0Vec<-c(1,1)
c0Vec<-diag(0.05,2)
y<-rnorm(123)

ssMod<-dlm(FF=FMat,V=Vmat,GG=GMat,W=WMat,m0=m0Vec,C0=c0Vec)
kFilter<-dlmFilter(y,ssMod)

kFilter$m
```

> kFilter$m
>               [,1]       [,2]
>   [1,]  1.00000000 1.00000000
>   [2,] -0.02417179 0.05107227

Comment: This is probably why you should finish reading the documentation before you jump into R.  The answer is discussed on page 5 of the dlm vignette, discussing time varying models.  If F is time-varying, dlm models accept a separate vector X (with values over time), as described by vector JFF.  There is a specific example regarding dynamic regression.

Answer (score 3):

There are many state space packages in R. See http://www.jstatsoft.org/v41/i04/paper for a review of them.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That was the first paper I read when trying to find an existing package that implemented the stat space model this way.  It didn't seem like any of them worked similar to my textbook after reading the underlying documentation, but maybe I missed something.  After reviewing the paper that I am trying to replicate again, it seems like I might need to write something myself regardless.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would re-define $y^*(t) = y(t) - A'x(t)$. You will have to rewrite the likelihood, as you say, to account for the parameters in $A$, but it is not that hard.